# How to replace numbers in multipe text files with powershell script

Tags: powershell

I have been using the script below to replace words in multiple text files stored in the same directory but when I want to change numbers (phone numbers +31 85 888 3156 replacing with +1 415 390 5045) I get a specific different number as output +49 800 723 84 68 ???

The words change and replace without any problem but the numbers I cannot figure out.
I am not a programmer but would like to get some feedback on how to find and replace numbers with the script below.

I used a scripts I found on the internet

```
Get-ChildItem 'path on computer*.html' -Recurse | 
ForEach {
    (Get-Content $_ | ForEach { $_ -replace '+31 85 888 3156', '+1 415 390 5045'}) | Set-Content $_ 
}
```

Every time the same end result. Text is replaced correctly but with the phone numbers I seem to get a calculation.

Comment: Please update your question with the actual patterns you use for `'replace'` and `'replace-with'`

Comment: Note that the [`-Replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#replacement-operator) takes a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) for the `'replace'` value, you better use the [.Net `Replace` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.replace) for literal `'replace'` values: `$_.Replace('replace', 'replace-with')`

Comment: Question updated with the actual patterns for 'replace' and 'replace-with'

Comment: So you need a literal replacement. Please either follow iRons advice or escape your phone number like this `[REGEX]::Escape('+31 85 888 3156')`